# multi-file itemtemplate should only add one of it's files once, even if the item is added many times

Tags: c#, vsix, itemtemplate

I have a solution which holds a VSIX project and an ItemTemplate Project. The item template has multiple files which are added when used. It looks like this:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="commands\$fileinputname$Command.cs">commands\TemplateCommand.txt</ProjectItem>

<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="descriptions\$fileinputname$.xml">descriptions\Template.xml</ProjectItem>

<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ui\$fileinputname$Designer.cs">ui\TemplateDesigner.txt</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ui\$fileinputname$DesignerDialog.cs">ui\TemplateDesignerDialog.txt</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ui\$fileinputname$DesignerDialog.Designer.cs">ui\TemplateDesignerDialog.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>

<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="userControls\UCTextBox_Label.cs">userControls\UCTextBox_Label.txt</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="userControls\UCTextBox_Label.Designer.cs">userControls\UCTextBox_Label.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>
```

This adds a Class file, an xml file, a Windows Form and a User Control. My froblem lies with the User Control. It is universally usable by all the items added by the template, so it only has to be created once. Is there a possibility of adding a logic to this file where it checks for the existence of this user control? Or is there a place for this somewhere else?

i.e. : If i'm adding 3 items using this template, i only want the User Control to be added once.